# How to efficiently resize an array of values, without boxing, used within a Dictionary<string, float[]>

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-3.0, resize, boxing

In the code below, Pages is defined as

```
 public SortedDictionary<DateTime, float[]> Pages { get; set; }
```

I am trying to dynamically increase the size of this array.  Can anyone tell how to increase the sized of the innermost float[]?

```
 var tt = currentContainer.Pages[dateTime];
 Array.Resize<float>(ref tt, currentContainer.Pages.Count + 1);
```

**Fail 1**

I tried the following code and get index out of range exception

```
    SortedDictionary<DateTime, float[]> Pages = new SortedDictionary<DateTime,float[]>();
    float[] xx = new float[1];
    xx[0] = 1;
    DateTime tempTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    Pages.Add(tempTime, xx);
    var tt = Pages[tempTime];
    Array.Resize<float>(ref tt, Pages.Count + 1);
    Pages[tempTime][1] = 2;
```

**Fail 2**

The following gives a compile time error (property, index, or dynamic member can't be used as a ref value)

```
    SortedDictionary<DateTime, float[]> Pages = new SortedDictionary<DateTime,float[]>();
    float[] xx = new float[1];
    xx[0] = 1;
    DateTime tempTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    Pages.Add(tempTime, xx);
    var tt = Pages[tempTime];
    // The line below is different from Fail 1 above ... compile time error
    Array.Resize<float>(ref Pages[tempTime], Pages.Count + 1);
    Pages[tempTime][1] = 2;
```

**Question**

What is the most performant answer to resize this array?

Would the answer change if it's likely that the final size will be 100-200 floats or 700-900 floats?

What if I change my allocation size from +1 to +128? .. or larger?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't just use `SortedDictionary<DateTime, List<float>>` instead?  You wouldn't need to resize anything.  Just call Add() on the list. ???

Comment: Does List, or Linked list guarantee the order of the floats? That is very important to me.

Comment: List<T> will cause a lot of boxing/unboxing for my float value type. Probably not the best choice

Comment: Using generic collections won't cause boxing/unboxing to occur.  When you specify List<float> the underlying array type of List is actually of type float.  Using a non-generic, weak typed collection such as ArrayList would cause an inordinate amount of boxing/unboxing.  Your best bet here really is to go with a List<float>.

Comment: If you declare the List to take type float it won't cause boxing

Comment: I don't understand what MSDN is saying re: List<T> vs ArrayList ... something about the 500th element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: The List<T> implementation takes up memory space with its additional methods and functionality. When the list reaches around 500 elements, the memory saved by _not_ boxing/unboxing overtakes the implementation size. In short, a List<T> with 500+ elements takes less memory to store than an ArrayList with the same number of elements, _as_ _well_ as the saved time from not having to box/unbox.

Comment: Is it true to say that, in short, an ArrayList is more efficient for less than 500 objects of a value type?

Comment: In terms of memory, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `List<T>`,

Example,

```
SortedDictionary<DateTime, List<float>> data;

data = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, List<float>>();

data.Add(DateTime.Now, new List<float>() { 11.4f, 322.3f, 33.5f });
```

EDIT:

How to get/set values from the list?

```
List<float> a = new List<float>()
{
  10.2f,20.3f
};

float v1 = a[0];
float v2 = a[1];

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", v1, v2);

a[0] = 90.40f;
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", a[0],a[1]);
```

Comment: Does List, or Linked list guarantee the order of the floats?  That is very important to me..

Comment: +1 using List. Both List and LinkedList preserve order (unlike Dictionary and HashSet). List is more like array...

Comment: +1 Brian. @makerofthings7 : It represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by index.

Comment: List<T> will cause a lot of boxing/unboxing for my float value type.  Probably not the best choice.

Comment: @makerofthings7 - I think you misunderstood the usage of List<T>.

Comment: See this for more explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403055/boxing-unboxing-and-generics

Comment: Thanks Divi, reading now.  See the link I posted under the question regarding MSDN and the 500 object mention.  That is throwing me off.

Comment: @Divi- It is all aobut usage of (memory)stack/heap.

Comment: So would I be a nitpick if I went with ArrayList if I average less than 300 objects?  Is the benefit on MSDN's link focused on memory usage, or performance?

Comment: If you go to ArrayList, you start to box/unbox.  Stick with `List<T>`.  This level of optimization is only necesecary if you know for sure that the code is a bottleneck.  `List<T>` is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

First, do consider using a `Dictionary<DateTime, List<Float>>`, instead of the array. Since your code examples all involved expanding the array size by 1, that implies to me that you're going to resize the arrays many times to get to their final size. If that's the case, then choosing a container that can expand on its own, and can do so efficiently, is going to be better.

Second, all your examples are using array lengths one greater than the number of items in the dictionary. That's an unusual relationship, are you sure that a `Dictionary<DateTime, (some group of floats)>` is the proper container?

That said, here's how to resize the array inside a Dictionary.

```
SortedDictionary<DateTime, float[]> Pages = new SortedDictionary<DateTime,float[]>();
DateTime date = DateTime.UtcNow;

float[] arr = Pages[date];
Array.Resize<float>(ref arr, arr.Length + 1);
Pages[date] = arr; // [] overwrites the old value, unlike Add().
```

Comment: Will frequent resize operations put pressure on the stack or the heap in this case?

Comment: On the heap. Or more specifically, you're making extra work for the garbage collector.

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing & reading, I'm comparing ArrayList, List<T>, and this method.  I'll be doing some analysis to see if I have more than 500 items in an Array to justify the List<T>

Comment: To answer your question, yes, I think that is the right choice container for my implementation.  I am collecting data at a specific point in time.  Each datapoint is a float.  The position of the float in the array gives it meaning.

Comment: After testing, this seems to be the most performant solution compared to List<T> if I increase my allocation size from +1 to +10 and keep the objects less than 300.

Comment: If you are collecting data at a specific point in time, why isn't `Dictionary<DateTime, float>` appropriate? If you have <n> sensors, wouldn't the array length be a constant <n>, not changing? (I don't mean to harp on this, it's just a rather unusual data structure.)

Answer (score 1):

Array.Resize(ref tt, Pages.Count + 1); 
Pages[tempTime] = tt;

Comment: Will frequent resize operations put pressure on the stack or the heap in this case?

Comment: List<float> will do much better work in resizng in relation to heap/CPU. If you call Array.Resize often (especially if you grow it by 1 as in your sample) it will put serious pressure on memory allocation and CPU for copying a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

public SortedDictionary< DateTime, float[]> Pages { get; set; },

you could use

public SortedDictionary< DateTime, List< float>> Pages { get; set; },

so you won't have to resize and if you still want to access it as an array, you can always use the ToArray() of the List class.

Hope this helps

Comment: List<T> will cause a lot of boxing/unboxing for my float value type. Probably not the best choice.

Comment: When it comes to collections, generics make it possible to avoid boxing by utilizing actual T[] arrays. List<T> for example uses  T[] array to store its contents. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403055/boxing-unboxing-and-generics

The array, of course, is a reference type and is therefore (in the current version of the CLR, yada yada) stored on the heap. But since it's a T[] and not an object[], the array's elements can be stored "directly": that is, they're still on the heap, but they're on the heap in the array instead of being boxed and having the array contain references to the boxes.

Comment: +1 for your links and comments on this post as a whole... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a List as suggested in the other answers. The reason you can't change the array with `Array.Resize()` is that it copies the array into a new array, for which it returns the reference for (Reflector output below) - so unless you re-assign the new value to `Pages[tempTime]` you are out of luck.

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
public static void Resize<T>(ref T[] array, int newSize)
{
    if (newSize < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("newSize", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
    }
    T[] sourceArray = array;
    if (sourceArray == null)
    {
        array = new T[newSize];
    }
    else if (sourceArray.Length != newSize)
    {
        T[] destinationArray = new T[newSize];
        Copy(sourceArray, 0, destinationArray, 0, (sourceArray.Length > newSize) ? newSize : sourceArray.Length);
        array = destinationArray;
    }
}
```